# How to get interval or timeout by ID

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout, setinterval, intervals

I want to get the data of an interval or a timeout through its ID.
Just like `document.getElementById('id-of-random-element')` will get all the data on that specific element, I want to know if there is any way possible to get the data that was originally set for a timeout or an interval by its ID.

For example:

```
var a = setInterval(()=>{console.log("abcdef");},1000)
//below is some serious pseudo code
getIntervalById(a) //returns something like (()=>{console.log("abcdef");},1000)
```

Comment: Interval timers don't return anything more than a numeric id used to clear them. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: just like you would be able to see lots of element data(for that specific) and maybe even edit from with ```document.getElement``` kind of code, I want to be able to see that amount of data from a timeout or an interval that was set. And yes I know that it only returns the "id" of sorts. It's y I'm here asking

Comment: What sort of data are you referring to and what would be your practical use case? So far all you have is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: and as to what problem I'm trying to solve, I mean.. that's only asked when it's unclear what the person wants.. How was I unclear? what i want is yes probably extremely hard, but at the very least is there a way to get the function that was passed in a certain timeout or interval by specific Id ```a```

Comment: No there is not unless you were to store a reference to it in an object or Map yourself using the id as a key

Comment: an xy problem? well the problem is once I set an interval or a timeout (or if one is set) I can't see what was set for it even if I have the ID

Comment: Correct. You still haven't identified a practical use case where that is problematic or what it is you really want to accomplish

Comment: and to be clear, I ACTUALLY WANT to see the function passed in any timeout or interval just by its ID

Comment: Then you need to store a reference to it yourself. There is no built in method to do what you are asking. The only thing that id can be used for natively is to clear the timer

Comment: hmm.. noted, the thing is, I am planning to make a coding game, and well there'd be "firewalls" people could make but it has to be crackable... the first thing someone's gonna do is have like a ```setInterval(()=>{/*reads commands to solve firewall piece by piece*/},1000000000)``` but I was wondering if people would evolve to see how to apply the solve and just clear the timer and move like that, but... if it's impossible... I'll just have to ensure that stalling in that nature can't be a verified firewall

Comment: I don't think you can even find id's for timers that aren't stored either. Don't think there is anything like `window.getAllTimers()`. They are a bit of a black box

Comment: also, finding the ID u can do that by natural painstaking process of a for loop trial and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might consider is to overload timers so you can intercept them and store whatever you might want

Simple example with setTimeout

```js
const origTime = window.setTimeout;

setTimeout = function(...args) {
  const id = origTime(...args);
  // do something with arguments and id
  console.log('id:', id, 'delay:', args[1]);
  return id
}

let id = setTimeout(() => console.log('wtf'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.log('foobar'), 2000)

console.log('external id', id)
```

Comment: btw, how does the ... link args like that?

Comment: Is ES6 spread.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other answer

```
var inters = []
Object.defineProperties(window, {
    getAllIntervals: {
        get: function () {
            return inters
        }
    }
})
var old= setInterval
setInterval = function () {
   var oldId= old.apply(this, arguments)
   inters[oldId] = arguments//[fnc, time]
}
```

Then whenever you can setInterval you can later call getAllIntervals to get the list of intervals mapped by us lidz and analyze the function with .toString() , or get a specific interval with `getAllIntervals[INTERVAL_ID]`

Comment: although your answer seems more complicated, it is still correct (thing is the dude below u I saw working on it first)

Comment: but still, please don't delete your answer. I'm interested in your method